# timepicker css problems with overflow

Tags: css

I am using antd Datepicker and Timepicker (React) and I have the following problem,
I cannot hide the overflow from the dropdown selector .It has so much empty space that it is not really user friendly

here is my code maybe u can help me set the overflow somehow

```
            <FormGroup className="timeInput">
                      <TimePicker

                      />
                    </div>
```

and my css :

```
   .noBorder input {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .timeInput{
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By overflow do you mean the white space that exists after the list of numbers, when you scroll down to the bottom?

.ant-time-picker-panel-select ul 
Is the class and element identifier for your CSS. 
Writing the code below into your css file should get you the effect that you want. Note that this will affect all time pickers that has access to your own styles

```
.ant-time-picker-panel-select ul
{
 padding: 0px;
}
```

[image: Snippet of the padding-bottom:160px on the element]

Comment: thats exactly what I mean . if u folow the link and try to set a time and scroll down you will see this ugly white space that I need to hide!

Comment: That is caused by default padding in a class on the UL element
Let me just get you some information.

Comment: how can i fix it?got any ideas?

Comment: .ant-time-picker-panel-select ul
Is the class and element identifier for your CSS.
Writing the code below into your css file should get you the effect that you want. Note that this will affect all time pickers that has access to your own styles
.ant-time-picker-panel-select ul{
padding: 0px;
}